# Node.js childprocess.execSync for curl request not returning error if curl request is 404 or 403

Tags: node.js, curl, child-process

this might not be an issue per say but here is my problem : I'm using childprocess.execSync to execute curl request on pages I need the html content of. It works perfectly fine for valid pages but if the curl request to a page encounters pretty much any error code such as 404 or 403, then the result of the execSync is empty and I have no way to know what error code the curl encountered.
Is there any way to know the curl error code that happens during the childprocess.execSync ?

node.js version : 8.16.2

Comment: Should we use the child process to execute the Curl request?

Comment: can you not use some library like `axios`, `got` etc to directly make the call instead of going indirectly?

Comment: I could look into it, but as I said execSync works great, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to return the errors from the curl I execute with it

Comment: `--fail` https://superuser.com/a/657174/48390

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way, look like I just had to pass "-i" with my curl request to return the response headers too and not just the body, now I can just parse that and see the error code I got.